# What's the size of the MaxMind MMDB binary GeoIP2 databases?

Tags: maxmind

What's the size on file system of the MaxMind GeoIP2 databases in binary format? I'm asking about both the country and the city level db.

Unfortunately I can't find this information anywhere.

I know the file size will change over time but I need to roughly estimate the storage requirements.

Also, does anybody know the memory footprint on a minimal console application that resolve a single ip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current City database is approximately 122 MB. The memory footprint would depend on the particular API you are using to read the file. Most of the official APIs memory-map the file so there is no need to load the whole database into real memory.

Comment: Actually I'm going to use the C# api on azure. Do you know if it actually uses memory mapped files on windows too? And which version of the database are you talking about? The city level or the country level?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the City database. The Country database is 2.7 MB. The official C# GeoIP2 API uses memory mapping by default.