# Maxmind DatabaseReader Java heap space

Tags: java, spring-boot, maxmind, geolite2, geolitecity

I try to use GeoLite2-City.mmdb in spring boot to get location data. To that effect, I created a bean like this in the configuration file:

```
        @Bean   
        public static synchronized DatabaseReader mmdbReader() throws IOException { 

               if ( reader != null ) {
                   return reader;
               }

                ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();

                Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:static/mmdb/GeoLite2-City.mmdb");
                InputStream database = resource.getInputStream();

               reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(database).fileMode(com.maxmind.db.Reader.FileMode.MEMORY)
                       .withCache(new CHMCache()).build(); 

           return reader;
        }
```

I also created a util function to retrieve the location like this:

```
     public static GeoLocation getLocation(HttpServletRequest request, DatabaseReader databaseReader) throws IOException, GeoIp2Exception{

      if(request.getRemoteAddr().equals("0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1") || request.getRemoteAddr().equals("127.0.0.1")) {
          return new GeoLocation("localhost", "Redmond", "USA", 47.673988, -122.121513);
      }

      InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(request.getRemoteAddr());

      CityResponse response = databaseReader.city(ipAddress);

      Country country = response.getCountry();
      City city = response.getCity();
      Location location = response.getLocation();

      return new GeoLocation(ipAddress.toString(), city.getName(), country.getName(), location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
      }
```

However, every time I deployed the app I get this error

```
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at com.maxmind.db.BufferHolder.<init>(BufferHolder.java:64)
    at com.maxmind.db.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:89)
    at com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader.<init>(DatabaseReader.java:64)
    at com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader.<init>(DatabaseReader.java:54)

    at com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader$Builder.build(DatabaseReader.java:160)
    at com.microsoft.apie.configuration.ApplicationConfiguration.mmdbReader(ApplicationConfiguration.java:104)
```

My java settings are:

```
  -Xms512m -Xmx2048m
```

Can you please assist?

Comment: How large is that file now? According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37483661/whats-the-size-of-the-maxmind-mmdb-binary-geoip2-databases it was rather small, but that was years ago.

Comment: @mentallurg, the DatabaseReader.java and Reader.java and BufferHolder.java are part of the maxmind library at:  https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/maxmind/geoip2/DatabaseReader.java

Comment: @tevemadar, the file size is 63,517,885  bytes; so roughly 65MB

Comment: You should use default fileMode which is MEMORY_MAPPED

Comment: @Strelok, it didn't work. I get this error:                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only FileMode.MEMORY is supported when using an InputStream

Comment: Well it's pretty obvious, don't use the constructor that takes InputStream, use the one that takes a File and read from file system.

Comment: It's a catch 20/20 situation:                                                                                                  a.) I can't use resource.getFile() because the app is packaged in a jar and thus throws a FileNotFoundException when using this option                                                                                             b.) And I can't use resource.getInputStream because the filemode MEMORY_MAPPED doesn't support that.                                                                                          You see my situation?

Comment: Perhaps that `InputStream` is not clever enough, in terms of positioning or something. A silly workaround to try would be reading it into a `byte[]`, and calling the API with a `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Comment: Just take the file out of the jar

Comment: The code provided actually works with GeoLite2-Country.mmdb which is a subset of GeoLite2-City.mmdb. I guess there's something datastructure used by maxmind that has some limitations in the data it can hold. I will investigate this further

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by doing this:

a. I removed the file GeoLite2-City.mmdb from the jar and put in the same folder than the jar

b. I refactored the method and this:

```
    @Bean  
    public static synchronized DatabaseReader mmdbReader() throws IOException { 

              if ( reader != null ) {
                  return reader;
              }

               /*ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();

               Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:static/mmdb/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb");

               InputStream database = resource.getInputStream();
              */
               FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource("/path/to/file/GeoLite2-City.mmdb");

              reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(resource.getFile()).fileMode(com.maxmind.db.Reader.FileMode.MEMORY_MAPPED)
                      .withCache(new CHMCache()).build(); 

          return reader;
   }
```

c. Repackaged the app and it works!

Thanks Strelok for this suggestion